# For loop stuck in if /else branches

Tags: java

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz game in Java, using IntelliJ, the GUI created through forms. I put the questions(label) + options(radiobutton) in a 2d array, the right answers and the user answers are also in 2 separate 2D array.

A *next* button changes the question+options, and before the last question it gets disabled and only the *submit* button is enabled.
However, the for loop, which should check if the user's answers are equal to the right answers and calculate the score is stuck in the if-else statement. If the first answer is right, it adds the scores up to the length of the userAnswer array, even if the answers are wrong. It's almost the same if the first answer is wrong, then the score is 0. In both cases it always prints out the first userAnswer or null (when its wrong) and first rightAnswer at each iteration.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class QuizGame extends JDialog {
    private JRadioButton radioButtonA;
    private JRadioButton radioButtonB;
    private JRadioButton radioButtonC;
    private JRadioButton radioButtonD;
    private JButton nextButton;
    private JButton submitButton;
    private JPanel quizGameForm;
    private JLabel title;
    private JLabel questionLabel;
    private JLabel questionNumber;
    ButtonGroup groupChoices;
    public static int abc = 0;

    String[][] questions = new String[10][5];
    String[][] rightAnswers = new String[10][2];
    String[][] userAnswer = new String[10][1];
    public int givenAnswers = 0;
    public static int count = 0;
    public int score = 0;

    //this method sets and clears the questionLabel and radioButtons texts
    public void startGame (int count){
        questionNumber.setText("" + (count + 1) + ". ");
        questionLabel.setText(questions[count][0]);

        radioButtonA.setLabel(questions[count][1]);
        radioButtonA.setActionCommand(questions[count][1]);

        radioButtonB.setLabel(questions[count][2]);
        radioButtonB.setActionCommand(questions[count][2]);

        radioButtonC.setLabel(questions[count][3]);
        radioButtonC.setActionCommand(questions[count][3]);

        radioButtonD.setLabel(questions[count][4]);
        radioButtonD.setActionCommand(questions[count][4]);
        groupChoices.clearSelection();
    }

    //connection with the GUIForm
    public QuizGame() {
        setTitle("Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!");
        setContentPane(quizGameForm);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1500, 750));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        submitButton.setEnabled(false);

            //questions and answer choices
            questions[0][0] = "In Monty Python's \"Michelangelo and the pope\" sketch, which of the following is not painted in the Last Supper?";
            questions[0][1] = "a kangaroo and a conjurer";
            questions[0][2] = "waiters and cabaret";
            questions[0][3] = "28 disciples";
            questions[0][4] = "one fat and two skinny Jesus Christ";

            questions[1][0] = "In Monty Python's \"Life of Brian\", what latin text did brian have to write on the walls a hundred times?";
            questions[1][1] = "Romanus eunt domus";
            questions[1][2] = "Romanus ite domi";
            questions[1][3] = "Romani ite domum";
            questions[1][4] = "Romani eunt domi";

            questions[2][0] = "In Monty Python's Flying Circus, which of the following vicious gang is not terrorising the cities?";
            questions[2][1] = "Keep left signs";
            questions[2][2] = "Hell's grannies";
            questions[2][3] = "Baby snatchers";
            questions[2][4] = "Stinky badgers";

            questions[3][0] = "Who directed The Meaning of Life?";
            questions[3][1] = "Graham Chapman";
            questions[3][2] = "John Cleese";
            questions[3][3] = "Terry Jones";
            questions[3][4] = "Micheal Palin";

            questions[4][0] = "When was the Monty Python group formed?";
            questions[4][1] = "1969";
            questions[4][2] = "1970";
            questions[4][3] = "1989";
            questions[4][4] = "1975";

            questions[5][0] = "What kind of group was Monty Python?";
            questions[5][1] = "writing group";
            questions[5][2] = "comedy club";
            questions[5][3] = "group of historians";
            questions[5][4] = "golf club";

            questions[6][0] = "How many people were in the group?";
            questions[6][1] = "6";
            questions[6][2] = "5";
            questions[6][3] = "8";
            questions[6][4] = "7";

            questions[7][0] = "Who wrote \"Monty Python and the Holy Grail\"?";
            questions[7][1] = "Graham Chapman, John Cleese and Terry Gillian";
            questions[7][2] = "Terry Jones and Michael Palin";
            questions[7][3] = "Graham Chapman, Terry Jones and Terry Gillian";
            questions[7][4] = "Hired writers";

            questions[8][0] = "What is Brian's last name in the \"Life of Brian\"?";
            questions[8][1] = "Cohen";
            questions[8][2] = "Colen";
            questions[8][3] = "Calnen";
            questions[8][4] = "Colman";

            questions[9][0] = "Who helped to fund the \"Life of Brian\"?";
            questions[9][1] = "Paul McCartney";
            questions[9][2] = "George Harrison";
            questions[9][3] = "David Gilmour";
            questions[9][4] = "David Bowie";

            //right answers
            rightAnswers[0][1] = "waiters and cabaret";
            rightAnswers[1][1] = "Romani ite domum";
            rightAnswers[2][1] = "Stinky badgers";
            rightAnswers[3][1] = "Terry Jones";
            rightAnswers[4][1] = "1989";
            rightAnswers[5][1] = "writing group";
            rightAnswers[6][1] = "5";
            rightAnswers[7][1] = "Graham Chapman, John Cleese and Terry Gillian";
            rightAnswers[8][1] = "Cohen";
            rightAnswers[9][1] = "George Harrison";


            groupChoices = new ButtonGroup();
            groupChoices.add(radioButtonA);
            groupChoices.add(radioButtonB);
            groupChoices.add(radioButtonC);
            groupChoices.add(radioButtonD);

            startGame(0);


            nextButton.addActionListener(ae -> {
                if (ae.getSource() == nextButton) {
                    //update the radio buttons
                    repaint();
                    radioButtonA.setEnabled(true);
                    radioButtonB.setEnabled(true);
                    radioButtonC.setEnabled(true);
                    radioButtonD.setEnabled(true);
                    givenAnswers = 1;

                    if (groupChoices.getSelection() == null) {
                        userAnswer[count][0] = "";
                    } else {
                        userAnswer[count][0] = groupChoices.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                    }

                    //disable Next button, enable Submit button after the penultimate question
                    if (count == 8) {
                        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
                        submitButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                    count++;
                    startGame(count);


                    //checking the user's answers and counting the score
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < userAnswer[k].length; k++) {
                    if (userAnswer[k][0].equals(rightAnswers[k][1])) {
                        score += 1;

                        //print lines to see if it goes into the if branch
                        System.out.println("here");
                        System.out.println(rightAnswers[k][1]);
                        System.out.println(userAnswer[k][0]);
                    } else {
                        score += 0;
                        //print lines to see if it goes into the else branch
                        System.out.println("there");
                        System.out.println(rightAnswers[k][1]);
                        System.out.println(userAnswer[k][0]);
                    }
                }
                //print out score
                System.out.println(score);
                System.out.println(abc);

            });


            submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                private int score;
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ScoreBoard myScore = new ScoreBoard();
                    myScore.score = this.score;
                }
            });
        }

        //start the quizgame
        public static void main (String[]args){
            QuizGame game = new QuizGame();
        }
```

So far I tried to use a while loop instead a for loop, but it ended up in an infinite loop and at some point it threw an error: "AWT-EventQueue-0" and .equals(Object) method is not working because this.userAnswer is (null). Then I separated the k++ and put at the end of the if and else statements, it behaves the same way. I tried to move the for loop, under the line:   if (ae.getSource() == nextButton) {               but it couldn't compile.

Now:
If the first answer is wrong, the output repeats: there, waiters and cabaret, 0, 0.
If the first answer is right, the output repeats even is the second answer is wrong: here,waiters and cabaret,waiters and cabaret, 1, 0

Comment: Rather than using parallel arrays, consider defining a `Question` class with fields `String questionText`, `Map<Character, String> options` and `char correctAnswer`. Also, you'll probably want to read these in from a file instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: thank you all for the help! @jsheeran I followed your advice  and defined the Question class, and read the text from a csv file. It's way better now, easier to handle, it works. thanks!